# Web service: How to go about it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I want to know if it is possible to create a web application in ASP.net that would be called by a URL request like www.site.com/param1=val1
Then my web app. is suppose to return  value back to the client.

For example Google API(Not sure though).

Actually, I have a web site page that has a text-box which takes a valid video link and shows N. of views in the same text-box for that video. The technique to do this is unique to each video sharing site as my programming logic uses string manipulation methods to extract the views value from the link of each site respectively depending on the pattern of the site's HTML page(source page). The technique works fine for around 10 sites now. But in this way I am limiting my clients to only 10 video sharing site.

This technique of extracting the views from video sharing site is a small part of a very large project.

So I was thinking to make this as a web service where client(my project) will request a URL with the video link as parameter and this web service will return N of views.This will help in reducing the complexity in managing the code and it will be easier to add code for extracting views from new sites in the future.

Is this possible? If it is then please show a demo code because I've never tried it and also let me know if it is a better way handling such situation.

This is same as creating a re-useable method/function that saves our time.

Comment: You can search around a bit about "REST" or "RESTful"

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can use WCF to do what you are saying... I can say that this is the preferred way to do it.

[Tutorial on how to install a WCF service in IIS 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

This tutorial has a sample service, and teaches how to install it in IIS 7.

**EDIT**

I found another tutorial on WCF: (this one has images so that you can look at what they are doing)

[Create RESTful WCF Service API: Step By Step Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/RestServiceAPI.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Miguel, I just went through the links. I will give it a try.

Comment: Fine... any questions, fell free to ask! =)

Answer (score 1):

To expand my comment a little:

**REST Service**

REST Services are Webservices reimplementing the alreadys existing HTTP methods (e.g. GET, POST, PUT, DEL) to perform for each request with the same parameters the same action. (e.g. with parameter sort=asc always return a list sorted by name ascending).

In .Net you can use WCF to build a REST Service

More Information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I've never heard of REST too :( And In your way I see that those are the predefined methods(sort=asc) where as in my case I want to pass a link to the service which will process that page by getting the source page of the link and then return me an integer value to indicate number of views of the video on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Moving forward I'd look at [WFC Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP).  You can install it via the Nuget package manager. Package description **[here](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/WebApi.All)**

Comment: Thanks MJ. Actually, I'm new to Web development and I've only worked with basic ASP.net web apps. so keywords like WFC and Nugetpackage are all mystery for me :P. But I will try that too.